# Multi Store RewriteBase Problem (Magento 2.3)

Tags: multistore, multidomain, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up a Magento 2.3 CE multi store installation. Most things are working fine:

Default website and magento admin are available on https://a.b.info (/admin_sdgshgd).

I created another website + store view + store and set the base urls to  https://c.b.info. Apache 2 config has been updated and seems to be working fine.

Now to the problem:

The default website (a.b.info) is referencing styles and js with /pub/static/*, so I had to set the RewriteBase to /public/static/ in the .htaccess file in the static folder.

The new website (c.b.info) is using /static/ (without /pub) - so this store works if I change RewriteBase to /static/.

That means, I can have either default and admin, or the new store working correctly, but not both.

I have no clue why the urls are with or without pub on the one hand and I have no idea either, how I could make both sites run correctly while they have different paths.

Here are the vhost configs:

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName a.b.info
    ServerAdmin info@b.info
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/b/httpdocs

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-magento.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-magento.log combined

    RewriteEngine On

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/b/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/b/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName          c.b.info
   DocumentRoot        /var/www/vhosts/b/httpdocs

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-c.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-c.log combined

   RewriteEngine On

   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "postelhq"
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/b/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/b/privkey.pem
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And that's the .htaccess excerpt:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
    RewriteBase /pub/static/  # works with a.b.info
    #Rewritebase /static/ # works with c.b.info

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
    # Detects if moxieplayer request with uri params and redirects to uri without params
    <Files moxieplayer.swf>
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
    </Files>


</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what could have gone wrong?
Thanks,
OG

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, but I don't know why..
With the second domain, I had to add pub/ at then end of the base urls.